# how to use boost::asio::write_at, in particular have prombel with param meaning

Tags: networking, boost, boost-asio

I trying to figure out,
but google can't help to me.
First param to me is more interesting.
I even read boost::asio documentation, but first param to me is still mistery.

Answer (score 0):

First parameter is an object supporting [SyncRandomAccessWriteDevice](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SyncRandomAccessWriteDevice.html) concept.

One model of this concept is [`windows::random_access_handle`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/windows__random_access_handle.html).